# Prevent deselect date (Bootstrap-datepicker sandbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a question about the [bootstrap-datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=component&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=2&minViewMode=1&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox).

When I select a random Date and then open the Popup again and click the same Date, the Input-Field clears. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

I need this because in my case the Input-Field is not allowed to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular, and have a directive defined that inserts this little snip of hacky javascript... you might be able to do something similar:

```
.on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    if (ev.dates && !ev.date && selectedDate)
    {
        // Fixes bug in bootstrap calendar without multiselect, where picking the same day unselects it
        $(this).datepicker('setDate',selectedDate);
    }
    else if (ev.date && ev.date!=selectedDate) selectedDate = ev.date;
});
```

By having a variable named "selectedDate" somewhere before the constructor for your datepicker, this additional event handler will store valid dates and strip the bogus deselection. You'll notice the event object passed includes the array "dates" when incorrectly deselected, and only "date" when correctly selected.